# VB.Net Parameterized LIKE query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-like

I am writing  a code that will filter account numbers with the format zone-rate-customer_number. An example of that is 125-12-35, where 125 is the zone, 12 is the rate and 35 is the customer number. In my search textbox, I want to enter the zone and the customer number, this will exclude the rate. Here is my code

```
        Dim search As String = txtsearch.Text
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE [account no] LIKE '%' + @search + '%'"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = Con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[account no]", search)
```

How can I be able to search in my table using only the zone and customer number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should collect the "zone" and "customer_number" separately (e.g., in separate text boxes). Then you can do a LIKE search using

```vb
' test data
Dim zone As String = "125"
Dim customer_number As String = "35"

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText =
            "SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE [account no] LIKE ?"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", zone & "-%-" & customer_number)
    Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While rdr.Read
            Console.WriteLine(rdr("account no"))
        Loop
    End Using
End Using
```